# Tortoisesvn checkout with ant

Tags: svn, ant

I have problems with TortoiseSVN checkout by ant task.

#### Environment variables

```
   SVN=c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
```

#### build.xml

```
<project name="svn-letu" basedir="." default="checkout">

  <!--  all properties are in build.properties -->
  <property file="constants.properties" /> 

  <!-- path to the svnant libraries. Usually they will be located in ANT_HOME/lib -->
  <path id="svn.classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>  

  <!-- load the svn task -->
  <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svn.classpath" /> 


  <property name="checkoutDest" value="${checkout.dir}"/>

  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${checkoutDest}"/>
  </target>

  <property name="svn-user" value="${svn.user}"/>
  <property name="svn-password" value="${svn.password}"/>
  <property name="svn-url" value="${project.svn.url}"/>

  <target name="checkout" depends="init">
    <svn username="${svn-user}" password="${svn-password}">
      <checkout url="${svn-url}" revision="HEAD" destPath="${checkoutDest}" />
    </svn>
  </target>

</project>
```

constants.properties

```
project.svn.url=https://svnmsq.ttt.com/letu/trunk/App
svn.user=Andrei
svn.password=11111
checkout.dir=proba
```

#### Folder lib

```
svnant.jar 
svnClientAdapter.jar
svnjavahl.jar
```

#### Error

```
Buildfile: d:\Ant Task\build.xml   [typedef] Could not load definitions from resource org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml. It could not be found.

init:

checkout:

BUILD FAILED d:\Ant Task\build.xml:36: Problem: failed to create task or type svn Cause: The name is undefined. Action: Check the spelling. Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared. Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

**Somebody please help me**

Comment: which version of svnant.jar do you have. Make sure that org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml exists in that jar. It is definitely in the 1.3 version but not in the 1.0.

Comment: Why would you like to checkout the project via ant file? Doesn't your CI Tools handle the job?

Comment: Thank's Oers.I change version and it's work.But I have another problem.

Comment: @KarzhouAndrew It will be better to create the new question for a new problem

Comment: @KarzhouAndrew i posted my comment as an answer. And Alex is right, please open a new question for the new problem. Otherwise it will be very confusing ;D

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need the javasvn.jar file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml` exists in that jar.
It is definitely in the `1.3` version but not in the `1.0`